# Creature's size and area of effect

Tags: dnd-5e, creature-size, area-of-effect

Let's suppose that an effect (like a spell effect) occurs in a 30 ft. radius centered around a certain point. If a Gargantuan creature is only partially inside this region, is it always affected by the effect? I'm referring to D&D 5e. Thank you.

Comment: What game are you asking about?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it. I have edited my question.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Hmm.  That _question_ is explicitly about faerie fire, and as the answers point out the wording of the faerie fire is different from, say, a cloud spell.  But OP here is asking in general.  OTOH some of the answers over there try to generalize beyond just faerie fire, so it might be that the answers there satisfy OP here even if it is not the same question.  I'm going to leave it to Leonardo to decide if it is a duplicate - not VingTC at the present time.

Comment: Yes, I found the linked question very useful and exhaustive. I apologize for the duplicate.